# Extract data from pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to create a list of data frames from a bigger data frame based on column value. The column `"ID"` can repeat for example `1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2`.

I want to create a list of data frames by extracting the rows until when the ID repeats over again back to 1. In this case the list should have 3 data with ID's: `1,2,3`, `1,2,3,4,5` and then `1,2`.

Can this be done without using a for loop?

Answer (score 4):

No need for loops.

```
>>> list(zip(*df.groupby(df.ID.diff().ne(1).cumsum())))[1]
```

Comment: Nice, and yes.... loops should be eradicated! I normally write this as this though: `[i for _, i in df.groupby(df.ID.diff().fillna(1).ne(1).cumsum())]`

Comment: And the fillna(1) is not necessary I think as the first value will be np.nan.

Comment: @AntonvBR nice comment :)

Comment: Or `list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), df.groupby(...)))`.

Comment: What if the column values repeat? For example if the data set is:
    
    1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,1,2

Then it should be: 
    
    0) 1,1,1,2,2,3,3
    1) 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5
    2) 1,1,2

Answer (score 0):

This is a common idiom in `numpy`: `np.where(np.diff(s) != 1)`.

You can leverage this and `np.split` to accomplish what you want:

```
s = df.ID.values
idx, *_ = np.where(np.diff(s) != 1)
np.split(s, idx + 1)
```

```
[array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2], dtype=int64)]
```